# Not able to open usb drives in Thunar, Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 using fluxbox

Tags: usb, mount, fluxbox

As the title states, I am unable to open usb drives from within Thunar. When I click the drive icon I get the following message: `Failed to mount volume, permission denied`
I installed Ubuntu with the mini.iso and after the base installation only Fluxbox, no other WM or DE. I log in via terminal and start xserver with  the command startx (xinit), no DM. I have been able to make a crude workaround with some scripts using pmount so that I can mount any drive from the Fluxbox menu, but I would like to be able to mount the drives from within Thunar. I have googled quite extensively but I have found no working solution. Any further information needed will be provided gladly.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was facing this problem as well. I added to ***~/.fluxbox/startup*** the following line (near the beginning)-

```
/usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &
```